# Server monitoring and alerting software?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, cacti

What software does everyone use to monitor hardware? I know about nagios and cacti, but does anyone use any other software?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 2):

[SolarWinds IPMonitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/ipmonitor/) is pretty useful. A bit like cacti or nagios, but more pleasing to the eye. Windows only, and not free (not even as in "free beer"), though. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.zabbix.com/ is fairly good too - comparable to Nagios and Cacti at least.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/index.php/Main_Page) is quite good, if you have a large number of servers and need to do very comprehensive monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

For server monitoring without needing to install any software on your server take a look at my company ServerMonitoringHQ.com [Server Monitoring](http://servermonitoringhq.com)

Answer (score 1):

To monitor the hardware of HP Proliant Servers and HP Blade centers i can recommend Nagios (or [Shinken](http://shinken-monitoring.org) if you want to be avant-garde) together with the plugin [check_hpasm](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_hpasm).

Answer (score 0):

I have used both [mon](http://mon.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) and [munin](http://mon.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). I like munin because of its simplicity and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

My company just started using Nagios mainly to keep track of uptime. What are its difficients that you would look for another solution ? Is it scale or lack of monitoring capability ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a service like Alertra (alertra.com) if you don't want to run the monitoring server yourself. We have been using this for about a year and have been very pleased with it.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com) for monitoring our systems.  We found it a lot easier to work with then OpenNMS.

Answer (score 0):

We use NAGIOS for everything, and `god` on a lower level/within a rails application.

I'd be glad to give you more details if you gave us more details about what specifically you're looking for or trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RHQ (http://rhq-project.org/ ). While it is not too strong on the hardware side, it provides support for many services. Graphing and alerting are available out of the box and suppor for new/other kinds of managed resources can be provided via plugins.
RHQ is open source and has just recently released version 4.0 with a nice new GUI. RHQ also offers a command line interface hat allows scripting.